# Ubuntu won't boot after GUI crash, now bad superblocks?

Tags: boot, grub2, initramfs

I'm experiencing some serious problems with Ubuntu 14.10 for a while.
Everything was working fine for a few months on version 15.04, after which my system just started crashing out of nowhere, by what was caused by some GUI problem; the taskbar was disappearing, after which every program would freeze.
Rebooting would then give me the error '*ACPI PCC probe failed*', sometimes combined with the boot process stopping at the GRUB commandline, or at a prompt which seems to be call 'iniframs'. In the last case I would see some errors like "*Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init. No init found. Try passing init=bootarg*".

I reinstalled the whole system to 14.10 using a LiveDisk, after which the problem was gone for a few months, but returned exactly the same last week.
This morning I booted from LiveDisk again, now running BootRepair, which suggested me to share a link whith some logs on this forum.
The logs: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13237424/

On another forum someone advised me to run a filesystem check on the root partition of the installed OS, with the command *sudo e2fsck /dev/sdc1*. This gave this response:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck /dev/sdc1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sdc1: recovering journal
e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to re-open /dev/sdc1

/dev/sdc1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

I really hope there is someone who can help me, since this makes my desktop totally useless, even reinstalling the OS doesn't help.

**UPDATE December 1, 2015:** After buying a new harddisk I experienced exactly the same problems, and I ended up finding someone suggesting me to change the SATA-cable between thye disk and the motherboard.
Guess what, this did the trick. So please, before buying a new disk, check your cable.

Comment: Some interesting numbers in your post. 15.04 hasn't been out for over a year. You then say you have problems with 14.10. Did you downgrade to a non-LTS (I think now out of support) version or did you mean 15.10 which just came out a couple of weeks ago?

Comment: Indeed, I didn't run 15.04 for over a year, but of course only for a few months. After the first problems I downgraded to 14.10, hoping that would fix the problems (it's not an LTS-version, but it wasn't giving me problems).

Comment: I was just making sure that we'd be able to understand it and be certain of what you meant. ;-) Is your hard drive throwing any SMART errors, perhaps?

Comment: I rewrote the question a few times, must be the cause of the wrong timing :)
Yesterday I did a SMART test on the disk from the LiveDisk, which was not showing any errors at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a laptop with a Samsung hd that started doing this (a crash, and a badblock on the following restart) and the SMART tool still gave an "ok" status.

Try to boot for a live CD or USB and [doing a search for bad blocks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Badblocks) on the disk/partition affected:

```
fsck -vcck /dev/<device-PARTITION>
```

(Warning: it is bound to be a *really slow* and long thing --- in the hour range). In my case, it listed a couple more. After repair it all worked ok during maybe a couple of weeks, and then I had another one. SMART still saying that the disk was ok.

I replaced the disk (with an SSHD, nice thing!) and now it's all working ok. So my advice is, at the first badblock --- make a backup every day and, at the second badblock, trash the disk and go for a new one.

(BTW - as commented in the question, checking the SATA cable is also worth a shot - random errors in different spots can be a telltale symptom).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
After executing the command I get the response `/dev/sdb is in use. e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.` I only boot the system from LiveDisk and immediately run a terminal to execute the command, do you know how the disk can be in use?

Comment: A lot of live disks mounts all the partition they find (xubuntu does this, at least). You have to `sudo umount` all of them... and notice that it's the partition you have to check (`/dev/sdb1` etc), not the disk (I know you know it, but well...)

Comment: Unmounting did the job!
However, `fsck -vcck /dev/sdb1` gave me the exact same results as I pasted in the first post, with the `Attempt to read block from filesystem...` message in it.

Comment: Argh.... seems really dead. I hope you have a good backup... I have no more ideas...

Comment: Well, looks like I'm allowed to go for a new disk. The prices for SSD disks seem to have dropped by 50% in the last few years, so at least I'm going to have quite a good deal.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidKunz you're welcome! I bought a Seagate hybrid SSD + HD disk and I am very happy with it.